# How many number of string an arraylist can hold?

Tags: java, arraylist, web-crawler, stack-overflow

I am trying to write a web crawler. when I am going through a large page my arraylist variable is not able to hold all the data. It is throwing below exception. 
Exception in thread **"Thread-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError".**

What is the best way to hold those urls, as I need to visit those urls and the child urls and so on.

I thought of saving into database or writing to a file, but those mechanism might slow down the crawler performance.

Answer (score 3):

> when I am going through a large page my arraylist variable is not able to hold all the data

That's not correct.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

`StackOverflowException` isn't caused by running out of `ArrayList` capacity, which is 2^31-1 entries. It is caused by excessive recursion.

Probably you aren't tracking URLs you've already visited, and encountering link cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The limit  for ArrayList capacity is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` theoretically. However it depends on the amount of memory which is available for JVM. If there is sufficient heap space available to store the strings then it will store a huge amount of string.